# Converting JSON to XML with groovy scripting

Tags: groovy

I am trying to convert the following JSON File into XML file using groovy scripting

```
{
    "quiz": {
        "sport": {
            "q1": {
                "question": "Which one is correct team name in NBA?",
                "options": ["New York Bulls","Los Angeles Kings","Golden State Warriros",
                    "Huston Rocket"],
                "answer": "Huston Rocket"
            }
        },
        "maths": {
            "q1": {
                "question": "5 + 7 = ?",
                "options": ["10","11","12",
                    "13"],
                "answer": "12"
            },
            "q2": {
                "question": "12 - 8 = ?",
                "options": ["1","2","3",
                    "4"
                ],
                "answer": "4"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but I'm getting this error after  executing the code
**Error Part**

```
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: question for class: java.lang.String
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: question for class: java.lang.String
    at json_xml$_run_closure1$_closure2$_closure3$_closure5.doCall(json.xml.groovy:13)
    at json_xml$_run_closure1$_closure2$_closure3.doCall(json.xml.groovy:12)
    at json_xml$_run_closure1$_closure2$_closure3.doCall(json.xml.groovy)
    at json_xml$_run_closure1$_closure2.doCall(json.xml.groovy:12)
    at json_xml$_run_closure1$_closure2.doCall(json.xml.groovy)
    at json_xml$_run_closure1.doCall(json.xml.groovy:11)
    at json_xml$_run_closure1.doCall(json.xml.groovy)
    at json_xml.run(json.xml.groovy:10)
```

can someone tell me  where I'm going wrong? It will be very helpful since my oncoming project is mostly on developing the script for this type of conversions using Groovy.I am new to coding field.

The script that i have written is this.
**CODE**

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder
import java.io.*
java.io.StringWriter
def f1 = new File("C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/1b adangals/groovy/JSON-XML/example_2.json")
def json = new JsonSlurper().parse(f1)
def writer = new StringWriter()
def xmlf = new MarkupBuilder(writer)
xmlf.quiz{
    subject('sport')
{q1{json.quiz.sport.q1.collect{s,t->
    question(t.question)
    options(t.options)
    answer(t.answer) }}
subject('maths')
{q1{json.quiz.maths.q1.collect{q,r->
    question(r.q1.question)
}}}   }
}   
println writer.toString()
```

My expected result will be like this

```
<quiz>
     <subject>sport</subject>
       <q1>
         <question>krlsfnwlkf</question>
         <options>NYB,LAK,GSW,HR</options>
         <answer>fsfwrfw</answer>
       </q1>
     <subject> maths</subject>
        <q1>
          <question>csfwf</question>
          <options>cadfa</options>
        </q1>
</quiz>
```

Comment: Whenever you are collecting entries of map I recommend you to use `map.collect{k,v-> ...}`

Comment: @daggett tried as you said but still the same error .I have edited the code part and the error part in the question.

Answer (score 0):

just remove `q1` from this kind of accessor `json.quiz.sport.q1.collect`

and you could use `with` instead of `collect` because you are taking one question/answer

```
xmlf.quiz{
    subject('sport')
    q1{
      json.quiz.sport.q1.with{i->
        question(i.question)
        options(i.options)
        answer(i.answer)
      }
    }
    subject('maths')
    q1{
      json.quiz.maths.q1.with{i->
        question(i.question)
        options(i.options)
        answer(i.answer)
      }
    }
}   
println writer.toString()
```

result:

```xml
<quiz>
  <subject>sport</subject>
  <q1>
    <question>Which one is correct team name in NBA?</question>
    <options>[New York Bulls, Los Angeles Kings, Golden State Warriros, Huston Rocket]</options>
    <answer>Huston Rocket</answer>
  </q1>
  <subject>maths</subject>
  <q1>
    <question>5 + 7 = ?</question>
    <options>[10, 11, 12, 13]</options>
    <answer>12</answer>
  </q1>
</quiz>
```

Comment: thanks@daggett .It worked and I modified the code to get the options individually by index slicing